# Xamarin DependencyService.Get in a background thread. Best practice?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin Forms project for iOS and Android. I am using a bluetooth diagnostic adapter to connect to a vehicle, which has native libraries for each platform for communications. In my main project I have a background worker that I start and stop whenever I want to look at messages. Inside that thread (basically a loop that reads and processes any new messages) I make a DependencyService.Get call to read messages. This all "works" fine though I am seeing timing issues (missed messages) and I am pretty sure it is due to the many hundreds of DependencyService.Get calls that happen inside that thread(I don't see this behavior in native iOS/Android Xamarin projects). Is there a better way to do this? Due I need to move this code into each platform instead? That would suck as it would be a lot of code duplication. Thanks for any insight/help.

Comment: you should only need to call Get() once - that gets your a reference to the native service.  You then use that reference to call whatever methods on that service you need.

Comment: Also *paragraphs* and *line breaks* are free on stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks Jason, good suggestion I should have done to begin with. Unfortunately I am still seeing the timing issue (~400ms delay, which is enough to throw off communication timing). Guess I will try moving this code into the platform project to see if it improves or my problem is elsewhere.

Comment: You should reduce the number of DependencyService.Get calls.

Comment: put down a flag which checks if the get call has been called

Answer (score 0):

I moved the background worker code into the iOS project and am still seeing the timing issue. Therefore it has nothing to do with the DependencyService.

Thanks for the help, I did learn I should just create one reference to Dependency.Get call. :)